# R, ggplot2: Centering and aligning wrapped text in geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following data:

```
Channel <- c("Episode", "Episode", "Episode", "Episode", "Episode", "Episode", "Episode", "Episode")
start.time <- c(0.000, 25.458, 48.712, 152.419, 179.055, 196.274, 212.693, 232.861)
stop.time <- c(25.458, 48.712, 152.419, 179.055, 196.274, 212.693, 232.861, 266.370)
Episode <- c("Prologue", "An episode title", "A longer episode title", "An really, incredibly long episode title", "I wish I knew how to make hjust work with wrapped text", "A sample title", "No one likes making reproducible examples", "Epilogue")

ep_df <- data.frame(Channel, start.time, stop.time, Episode)
#wrap text for episode titles
ep_df$Episode <- stringr::str_wrap(ep_df$Episode, 15)
```

I use this code to plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ep_df, aes(fill = Episode, color = Episode)) + 
  geom_rect(color = "black", aes(xmin = start.time, xmax = stop.time, ymin = -0.5, ymax = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 15)) +
  facet_grid(Channel ~ .) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  coord_fixed(40)+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8F8F8", "#F5F5F5", "#F0F0F0", "#E8E8E8", "#E0E0E0", "#DCDCDC", "#D8D8D8", "#D3D3D3", "#D0D0D0", "#C8C8C8")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  geom_text(hjust = -0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 2, aes(x = pmin(start.time, (start.time+stop.time)/2), y = 0, label = Episode), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 0)) +
  labs(x = "Time (sec)") +
  ylab(NULL)
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image: plot_output]

I have two problems:

1. When using `hjust` to align the text in each rectangle, it appears to apply only to the first line of the wrapped text, the following lines seem randomly adjusted. I would like each line of an instance of wrapped text to be aligned.
2. I also cannot figure out how to center the text in each block, `hjust` won't seem to do it. It is possible to center each text value regardless of the size of the rectangle?

If 2) is not possible, that's OK, I can live with that, but 1) is a deal-breaker, I gotta have that wrapped text aligned to the same left edge (that's not flush against the left border of the box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for this question, I've found the solution by using the following `geom_text`

```r
geom_text(
    hjust = 0.5, 
    vjust = 0.5, 
    size = 2, 
    aes(
      x = (start.time + stop.time) / 2, 
      y = 0, 
      label = Episode
    ), 
    inherit.aes = FALSE
    )
```

It produced the following plot

[image: plot with a centered text in each block]